# Why does postgres return Username: null after first two values?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

This code returns the array [Joseph Miller Username: null]. The first two values in the array are correct and expected, but it should contain two more values instead of 'Username: null'. Can anyone explain why this might be happening or how to fix it?

```
 public List<User> getUserCredentials(String username){

        List<User> credentials = new ArrayList<>();

        try(Connection connection = getConnectionUtil().getConnection()){

            String sql = "SELECT first_name, last_name, password, user_id from users where username = ?";
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, username);

            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()){
                credentials.add(
                        new User(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getInt(4))
                );
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return credentials;
    }
```

Comment: Please add your User class to your question.

Comment: `new User(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getInt(4))` does not appear to take a `username`.

Comment: The root of this problem was actually in my overridden toString() method in my User class. It was printing out null because that method called instance variables besides the ones I was pulling from the DB